# jquery regex for folder name like windows 7

Tags: jquery, regex, directory

Below is my regex

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/);
```

I want this pattern to be changed to match like folder name creation restriction in windows 7 which doesn't allow below

```
\/:*?"<>|
```

How should I change my pattern to achieve this? I never wrote regex on my own as of now, I definitely will learn this soon.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you need more than just disallow these chars, see [*Naming Conventions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: No need to follow the naming conventions completely, I just want to restrict above characters from entering. That's fine for me.

Comment: Ok, so, you just want the whole string to consist of chars other than those `\/:*?"<>|`? Then use `/^[^\/:*?"<>|]*$/.test(val)` (`*` will also allow empty values)